# Optimal loop function exit

Tags: python, function, loops

Let's say there is a function returning nothing, which has a loop in it. At some point function call has to be finished (while in a loop). To be clear loop will always iterate multiple times.There are 2 ways to do that:

1.ending loop with `break`:

```
def func():
    while True:
        do_smth....
        if condition:
            break
```

2. ending function call right away with `return`:

```
def func():
    while True:
        do_smth....
        if condition:
            return
```

There should be no difference it terms of what these function actually do, but which way would be more efficient?

Comment: Your example is too limited to really say what would be best overall. In your given example, the optimal solution would not be to loop at all since it'll exit after one iteration

Comment: If you have a genuine case where this actually makes any kind of significant difference I will be astounded ... :) Remember, it's Python. Keep it simple and don't try and pre-optimise.

Comment: While true is generally not adviced. Break is mostly not recommended. If function returns nothing, it should not return anything. Question and code is too general. What you wrote there can (and should) be refactored as `while not condition: do_smth`. But this is basic programming, nothing to do with python or efficiency of break/return, which btw should not have an impact on your code. In any case, is `func()` inside another loop?

Comment: @MikeMajara No `func()` in not looped. Obviously all of that makes almost no difference in terms of performance but should one of these be the 'right way' to do it?

Comment: Yeah so then the 'right way' would be neither of them. They would be both wrong. You can see this kind of workarounds in some very special cases in which the alternative is way worse (in terms of readability in most cases). Both examples you wrote lead to illegible code and more often than not, to bugs. In any case, "optimal" option in terms of performance is out of the question as you are not measuring big-O of nothing here. As for the rest, rule of the thumb: avoid that pattern. also check the [zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @MikeMajara very well put!

Comment: Although this is python you asked about, to stretch it a bit more, you might want to check other [similar questions...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=break+vs+return)

Answer (score 1):

Running 'count to 10' loop 10 mln times with `timeit.timeit` shows that direct `return` runs slightly faster, so probably should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the 2 methods are inherited in their purpose.

the `break` statement is meant to used inside a loop and stop the iteration when getting to the `break`.

the `return` statement is meant to stop function execution and return a value.

the difference in the timing is caused be the procedure that start when getting to `break`/`return`; You can see, at the instruction level, the statements do different things -> causing to different timings:

```
import dis

def x():
    while True:
        return

def y():
    while True:
        break


print(dis.dis(x))
print(dis.dis(y))
```

The output is:
for `x`:

```
4           0 SETUP_LOOP               4 (to 6)

  5           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 RETURN_VALUE
        >>    6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

for `y`:

```
  8           0 SETUP_LOOP               6 (to 8)

  9     >>    2 BREAK_LOOP
              4 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
              6 POP_BLOCK
        >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

So its clearly that if you just comparing the difference in the *dummy example* you gave the `return` will be faster.

Comment: Clear enough.  But does it really matter is loop dummy or not? All lines will be executed in the same way with same timings, except for one we are talking about. Guess it is just less text then ).

Comment: @D.Moiseev it depend on what you want the loop to do; it won't always be as simple as that. but for just the sake of this over simple `while True` that you posted it serve the point

Answer (score 0):

Optimal is used to describe the best performance of code (big-O notation). The only case in which the question would be reasonable to answer to, is if `break` or `return` where in a loop, and you had to exit as fast as possible due to a complex procedure >O(n) in which you `break`ed lots of times, which would really be a rare case, and a clear indicator of bad design. As you can see from other answers, not even in this cases would it have a high impact in your code.

Now, supposing "optimal" refers to code in general, neither of the options chosen are good at all. In general that code snippet should be translated to

```
def func():
    while not condition:
        do_smth....
```

break/empty return are used in **very** specific cases for the sake of readability and I would say never for efficiency reasons.